# Error 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, lista

Soy semi nuevo en python y estoy haciendo una representación de un juego de cartas, el programa tiene que mezclar la baraja y repartir las cartas a 3 jugadores, el problema es que me salta error al imprimir las cartas de cada jugador.

```
'list' object is not callable
```

El codigo es este:

```py
#Imports
from random import randrange, choice
import random

#Cartas del Juego
E1 = "1(E)"
E2 = "2(E)"
E3 = "3(E)"
C1 = "1(C)"
C2 = "2(C)"
C3 = "3(C)"
B1 = "1(B)"
B2 = "2(B)"
B3 = "3(B)"
M1 = "1(M)"
M2 = "2(M)"
M3 = "3(M)"

#Mezcla de bajara
Baraja = [E1, E2, E3, C1, C2, C3, B1, B2, B3, M1, M2, M3]
random.shuffle(Baraja)

#Jugadores y sus cartas
Jugador1 = []
Jugador2 = []
Jugador3 = []
Jugador1.append(Baraja(0), Baraja(1), Baraja(2), Baraja(3))
Jugador2.append(Baraja(4), Baraja(5), Baraja(6), Baraja(7))
Jugador3.append(Baraja(8), Baraja(9), Baraja(10), Baraja(11))
print("Las cartas del jugador 1 son: "+Jugador1)
print("Las cartas del jugador 2 son: "+Jugador2)
print("Las cartas del jugador 3 son: "+Jugador3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

he estado revisando tu código y he visto varios fallos que ahora te comentaré, primero voy a mostrar mi código:

```py
#Imports
from random import randrange, choice #Esta línea sobra si importas toda la librería como lo estas haciendo en al línea de abajo
import random

#Cartas del Juego
E1 = "1(E)"
E2 = "2(E)"
E3 = "3(E)"
C1 = "1(C)"
C2 = "2(C)"
C3 = "3(C)"
B1 = "1(B)"
B2 = "2(B)"
B3 = "3(B)"
M1 = "1(M)"
M2 = "2(M)"
M3 = "3(M)"

#Mezcla de bajara
Baraja = [E1, E2, E3, C1, C2, C3, B1, B2, B3, M1, M2, M3]
random.shuffle(Baraja)

#Jugadores y sus cartas
Jugador1 = []
Jugador2 = []
Jugador3 = []

#la función append() solo recoge un valor, por lo tanto he tenido que hacerlo de esta manera

Jugador1.append(Baraja[0])
Jugador1.append(Baraja[1])
Jugador1.append(Baraja[2])
Jugador1.append(Baraja[3])

Jugador2.append(Baraja[4])
Jugador2.append(Baraja[5])
Jugador2.append(Baraja[6])
Jugador2.append(Baraja[7])

Jugador3.append(Baraja[8])
Jugador3.append(Baraja[9])
Jugador3.append(Baraja[10])
Jugador3.append(Baraja[11])

#Y por último, aquí he cambiado los + por , porque en python no se puede concatenar str con listas, en cambio si lo hacemos con , si se puede

print("Las cartas del jugador 1 son: ", Jugador1)
print("Las cartas del jugador 2 son: ", Jugador2)
print("Las cartas del jugador 3 son: ", Jugador3)
```

Muestra que el código funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te hayas servido de ayuda. ¡Un saludo!

Comment: +1 por dar un código probado.

Comment: Ahora lo entiendo todo, muchísimas gracias por ayudarme con eso!!!

Answer (score 1):

Vamos viendo:

```
Jugador1.append(Baraja(0), Baraja(1), Baraja(2), Baraja(3))
```

Para recuperar los elementos de una lista, se usa `[]`, no `()`.

`append` recibe un sólo parámetro; le estás pasando cuatro. Tampoco hay necesidad de hacer `append`; puedes inicializar directamente:

```
Jugador1 = [Baraja[0], Baraja[1], Baraja[2], Baraja[3]]
```

o, más corto, usando rebanado de listas:

```
Jugador1 = Baraja[0:4]  # Ojo con el índice final, tiene que estar pasado en 1.
```

Tampoco puedes concatenar una lista con una cadena en

```
print("Las cartas del jugador 1 son: "+Jugador1)
```

pero puedes simplemente imprimir una a continuación de la otra:

```
print("Las cartas del jugador 1 son: ", Jugador1)
```

Esto imprime:

```
Las cartas del jugador 1 son:  ['3(B)', '1(E)', '3(C)', '1(B)']
```

que se ve feo. Lo puedes arreglar usando el operador `*` delante de la lista.

```
print("Las cartas del jugador 1 son: ", *Jugador1)
```

que produce

```
Las cartas del jugador 1 son:  3(C) 2(B) 2(E) 2(M)
```

El operador `*` reemplaza la lista con sus valores individuales. El resultado es como si escribieras:

```
print("Las cartas del jugador 1 son: ", Jugador1[0], Jugador1[1], Jugador1[2], Jugador1[3])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudaste mucho.